# xelatex.exe failed

Tags: xetex

Could you help me please. 
I use windows 8.1 64 bit, MiKTeX 2.9, and I can't use xelatex with texmaker, when I compile I get this message with all my files: `log file not found`.
I tried `settings(admin)->formats -> build format` without success!
I get this transcript  :

```
Creating the xelatex format file...
Running miktex-xetex.exe...
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (INITEX)

entering extended mode

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/latexconfig/xelatex.ini"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latex.ltx"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\texsys.cfg")

./texsys.aux found





\@currdir set to: ./.





Assuming \openin and \input 

have the same search path.





Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.



catcodes, registers, compatibility for TeX 2,  parameters,

LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>

hacks, control, par, spacing, files, font encodings, lengths,

====================================



Local config file fonttext.cfg used



====================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\fonttext.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fonttext.ltx"

=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omlenc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omsenc.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1cmr.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1cmr.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1cmss.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ot1cmtt.fd")))

====================================



Local config file fontmath.cfg used



====================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\fontmath.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontmath.ltx"

=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===



("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omlcmm.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omscmsy.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omxcmex.fd")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ucmr.fd")))

====================================



Local config file preload.cfg used



=====================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\preload.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\preload.ltx")) page nos., x-ref,

environments, center, verbatim, math definitions, boxes, title, sectioning,

contents, floats, footnotes, index, bibliography, output,

===========================================

Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used

===========================================

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\hyphen.cfg"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\xebabel.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyphen\hyphen.tex")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyph-utf8\loadhyph\loadhyph-af.tex"

UTF-8 Afrikaans hyphenation patterns

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyph-utf8\patterns\tex\hyph-af.tex")

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyph-utf8\patterns\quote\hyph-quote-a

f.tex"))

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyph-utf8\loadhyph\loadhyph-grc.tex"

UTF-8 Hyphenation patterns for Ancient Greek

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\hyph-utf8\patterns\tex\hyph-grc.tex"

! Nonletter.

l.44 Î±

       1 Îµ1 Î·1 Î¹1 Î¿1 Ï…1 Ï‰1 ÏŠ1 Ï‹1 á¼€1 á¼1 á¼‚1 á¼ƒ1 á¼„1 á¼…1 á¼†1 ...

No pages of output.

Transcript written on xelatex.log.


Sorry, but miktex-makefmt did not succeed for the following reason:

  miktex-xetex.exe failed on xelatex.ini.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Haouam/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Haouam/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

My MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

any advice ?

Comment: Looks like you've got an older `latex.ltx`: you'll need to update your installation (I suspect `latex.ltx` and `xelatex.ini` are mis-matched).

Comment: How to correct update ? I have updated several times

Comment: Did you update as admin *and* user? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: Did you update as admin *and* user? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388